# oracle forms designer has stopped working when opening forms having webutil

Tags: forms, oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I have oracle 10g version 10.1.2.3.0 installed in my machine. I already configure webutil in my machine but still I am having problem that when I open any form which contains webutil library attached with it, form closes itself by giving error **Oracle Forms Designer has stopped working**. I don't know why I am getting this error can anybody guide me to solve this problem?

Comment: Few questions that will help: What OS are you on?  Was it working previously and it just stopped, or has it never worked?  Is this a new setup on a new machine?

Comment: OS: windows 8.1.
haven't used webutils before using them first time on the machine.
yes I have reinstalled oracle 10g and configure webutils but no progress.

Comment: I'm admittedly not well-versed with webutils, but in general, I've had issues with Forms and Reports Builder on anything above Windows 7.  I don't believe Oracle has certified that version beyond Vista, even.  Do you have a Windows 7 machine or even a VM you can test on?

Comment: No sir I dont have any machine having windows 7. I can create a VM. Then I'll test on it.

Comment: @AhmedTalha I had same problem, please check webutil, and also open forms after connecting to databse.